# Shopify Display selected variant stock dynamic

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to display the selected variant stock value in shopify.
I am able to show the stock of the current selected or when i reload the browser of the selected variant but it doesn't seem to change when I select other variants

```
<div id="variant-inventory" class="my-variant-inventory">
 {% if product.variants.first.inventory_management == "shopify" %}
    {% if product.variants.first.inventory_quantity < 6 %}
  Only <span class="nuStock">{{ product.variants.first.inventory_quantity }}</span> left!
    {% else %}
  <span class="myStock"></span>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: You need to find the JS callback that is called on variant change and do that there.

Comment: where can I find the JS to be call back?

Comment: It depends on the theme. Generally, it somewhere in the main JS file. Try to search for `selectCallback`. On old Debut themes, there was such a callback function.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried looking for that selectCallback but didn't find it. I check the product-form, product-template, product.liquid, theme.liquid and theme.js. Here is m theme JS
https://pastebin.com/00RDCesd

Comment: Look for "_onSelectChange", this is a callback you're looking for.